Approximating a Binomial Expansion using Error Functions
Let $P_n(z) = \frac{1}{2^n}(1-z)^n = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^n} \frac{{n \choose k}}{2^n} (-z)^k$.
If we let $X \sim B(n, \frac{1}{2})$ (that is X is a random variable following a binomial distribution with parameters n and p = 1/2),
then $P_r\{X = k\} = \dfrac{{n \choose k}}{2^n}$.
So we can rewrite our binomial expansion for $P_n(z)$ as
$P_n(z) = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^n} P_r\{X = k\} (-z)^k$.
If we let $Y = \dfrac{X - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}}$, then the central limit theorem tells us that as n gets large, $Y \rightarrow Z$, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.
Using continuity correction, we could then conclude that for n large, $P_r\{X = k\} \approx P_r\{\frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} - 1/2 < Z < \frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} + 1/2\} = \frac{1}{2}( \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} + 1/2}{\sqrt{2}})- \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} -1/2}{\sqrt{2}})). $
So my question is, is it reasonable to conclude that
$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^n} \frac{1}{2}( \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} + 1/2}{\sqrt{2}})- \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\frac{k - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} -1/2}{\sqrt{2}})) (-z)^k \approx \frac{1}{2^n}(1-z)^n $ for large $n$. And if so, can we say anything interesting about the error introduced by using the error functions as our coefficients. That is, are we getting an additive or multiplicative error, and can we get a good bound for the error incurred?
